AWS Ingress not working as expected title is coming react app , but content is being served properly getting 404
I am doing a project i have deployed alb-ingress-controller and there are services deployed in EKS
after adding ingress alb is created ,but my services are not being rendered properly .
This is the ingress resources , services and port , while i am running those services as images they are running fine.
Any Idea what is going wrong , i have deployed alb-ingress-controller with helm
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: applications-ingress
  namespace: applications
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}]'
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /mocktest
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mocktest-frontend
                port:
                  number: 4000
          - path: /library-app
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: library-app
                port:
                  number: 3000

Used flux for infra deployment
this helm release file , any one any idea on whats going wrong here
sample error : http://k8s-applicat-applicat-3e293401b4-218248430.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/library-app
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
spec:
  releaseName: aws-load-balancer-controller
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: aws-load-balancer-controller
      version: 1.8.2
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: eks-charts
      interval: 1h
  values:
    clusterName: eks-project
    serviceAccount:
      create: false
      name: aws-load-balancer-controller
  interval: 1h

same errors for both services one is nextapp or is react app , not able fetch files
enter image description here
and again deployed nginx service :
nginx:latest

that too is giving 400


/mocktest returns 200 but not loading for some JS, the library path are returning a custom 404 page so does your backend service the prefix specified  /library-app ?

got the issue , static files are not returned , the files are located on some other path ,trying it now , I have rebased whole react app to run on sub directly
added "homepage": "/mocktest-app" to package json and added basename in react router
now do  i need changes to nginx server also , where do i need place my files and what ingress should be ??

server {
    listen 4000;
    server_name _;

    location /mocktest-app/ {
        alias /var/www/build/mocktest-app/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /mocktest-app/index.html;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        alias /var/www/build/mocktest-app/static;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}

dist conf
docker commands :
COPY ./mocktest-frontend/build/ /var/www/build/mocktest-app
WORKDIR /var/www/build

Based on your comments if I got it right you should modify the Nginx configuration (that suppose you serve your static files from Nginx):
server {
    listen 4000;
    server_name _;

    # Serve the main app files
    location /mocktest-app/ {
        alias /var/www/build/mocktest-app/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /mocktest-app/index.html;
    }

    # Serve static files 
    location /mocktest-app/static/ {
        alias /var/www/build/mocktest-app/static/;
        expires max;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}

That suppose you done the copy of your build app to mocktest-app directory
COPY ./mocktest-frontend/build/ /var/www/build/mocktest-app/
WORKDIR /var/www/build

The ingress should have a path of /mocktest-app that forward requests to a k8s service mocktest-frontend
 spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /mocktest-app
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mocktest-frontend
                port:
                  number: 4000

